# Count number of * from text file

Tags: java, count

I have this code to count the number of * from a string entered. but I need to find it from an text file. Any idea?

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CountStars {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
      BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      System.out.println("Enter the String:");
      String text = bf.readLine();

      int count = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
          char c = text.charAt(i);
          if (c=='*' ) {
              count++;
          }
      }
      System.out.println("The number of stars in the given sentence are " + count);
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? What isn't working? What is? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: class name is `CountVowels` which counts `*`. Nice..

Comment: You can find `BufferedReader` constructor that reads from a file from docs.. BTW, you should use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File%29) class to read input from file..

Comment: @KingsIndian - Specs change :)

Comment: The code works fine... My problem is to read from a text rather than inputing string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write something as simple as below:

```
            int count= 0;
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("test.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
            String text; 
            while((text= br.readLine()) != null) { 
                   for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
                      char c = text.charAt(i);
                      if (c=='*' ) {
                           count++;
                      }
                   }                
                } 

                System.out.println("Count Stars = "+ count);
```

Comment: We can assume this was an assignment Yogendra, please don't post direct answers for assignments.

Comment: Sure. Will take care. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a `FileInputStream` and a `InputStreamReader` together, while specifying the [character-encoding](/questions/tagged/character-encoding). `"UTF-8"` is a pretty safe bet. Then read each line and count the number of `'*'` characters as you already did. Then create a grand total and don't forget to close the file afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Replace BufferedReader line with below lines.

```
Path path = Paths.get(aFileName);
BufferedReader bf = Files.newBufferedReader(path, ENCODING)
```

where aFileName is the file path, you can either use args or make a function.

Update1:
Thanks owlstead.
Use following line if version < 7.

```
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (aFileName));
```

Regards,
Tamour

Comment: Note: this answer requires Java 7.